# Shiny selectInput very slow on larger data (~15,000 entries) in browser

Tags: r, shiny

I have this basic shiny app, and it is blazing fast in the 'Viewer', but when I use the 'Open in Browser' option, the select input choices take a while to load.

```
selectList <- sapply(1:15000, function(x) paste(sample(letters, 10), collapse = ''))
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('mylist', 'Select Something',
              choices = c(Choose = '', selectList),
              selected = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

According to this thread - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/doHpFM6ZOGg, the issue had a fix in some old private branch. Latest install I am using is this and I see the slowness problem.

```
packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘0.13.2’
```

Any options I have to make this behave differently?

**Additional need:**

I would also like the selectized inputs to be dependent on a radio button input as follows. But, for some reason, I can't make the server side selectize input to work with observeEvent on the radio button. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
# mylist
selectList1 <- sapply(1:15000, function(x) paste0(x, "_", paste(sample(LETTERS, 10), collapse = '')))
selectList2 <- sapply(1:15000, function(x) paste0(x, "_", paste(sample(letters, 10), collapse = '')))

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = 'mylist', label = 'Select Something',
    choices = NULL,
    selected = 1
  ),
  radioButtons('letterType',
               'Select a Letter Type:',
               choices = c('Upper Case' = 'upper',
                           'Lower Case' = 'lower'),
               selected = 'upper',
               inline = TRUE)
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selectListReactive <- reactive({
    validate(need(is.null(input$letterType), FALSE))
    if (input$letterType == 'upper')
      selectList1
    else
      selectList2
  })
  observeEvent(input$letterType, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = 'mylist',
                         choices = c(Choose = '', selectListReactive()),
                         server = TRUE)
  })
}

# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? How can you expect a user to scroll through 15,000 options? There might be a better way to get at what you want if you provide more detail on what you are trying to do

Comment: These are ordered values, and also with the ability to search / select, it is not a terrible UI option. Do you have an idea for other Shiny UI elements that work better? Text box is much worse, I think.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hi try to put the choices in the server with `updateSelectizeInput` and use `server = TRUE` to store the choices server-side, e.g. :

```
library("shiny")
# mylist
selectList <- sapply(1:15000, function(x) paste0(x, "_", paste(sample(letters, 10), collapse = '')))
# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = 'mylist', label = 'Select Something',
    choices = NULL,
    selected = 1
  )
)
# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = 'mylist', choices = c(Choose = '', selectList), server = TRUE)
}
# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You have to use `selectizeInput` and not `selectInput` for this to work

Comment: This is very promising. Thank you. Can you take a look at my 'additional need' and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your `validate` you need `input$letterType` to be NOT null, so use `!is.null(input$letterType)` (with an exclamation mark) as condition

Comment: OMG - what a silly mistake on my part. Everything works like a charm in my original app based on this reproducible example and your solution. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use placeholder here?  It keeps defaulting to first in list.  Should I use solution below if need/want to use placeholder?

Answer (score 10):

I did it faster with **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)
selectList <- as.data.table(sapply(1:15000, function(x) paste(sample(letters, 10), collapse = '')))
names(selectList) = ""

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('mylist', 'Select Something',
              choices = c(Choose = '', selectList),
              selected = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This does not change anything when you open in a browser by giving it selectList$V1 as the choices.

Comment: You should not give  selectList$V1 as input, because it is a character vector and that is inefficient. You have to give selectList which is a data.table with 15000 rows and one column and it is more efficient.It is worked for me in a browser. Just copy and paste my script and check it

Comment: This made everything 1000x faster for me. It still might be good to do stuff server-side for some uses, but this worked with ~50,000 choices for me.

Comment: This works much better than the other solution, as the server-side rendering seem to cause lagging.

Comment: Huge speedup with this approach! However, I get "." at the top of the selectize list using this. Any way to remove that?

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. This works really well also for me. I would also need to remove the column name at the beginning of my sequence in menu, any idea?

Comment: @reisner and @nd091680 you can try to add the following line `names(selectList) = ""`. I also updated the answer with the solution. I hope it helps

Comment: interesting ... this doesn't work with Shiny 1.7.4 and data.table 1.14.2, but it does work if you again remove the `names(selectList)=""`.... 
But why does it work anyway? what sort of weird magic is data.table doing?