# updateSelectInput very slow over Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, deployment, shiny

I have a Shiny app that runs perfectly on the system but when I deploy it, it takes around 2 minutes to render a graph. I think the problem is due to updateSelectInput that I have but how can I make the shinyapps deployed program to be fast? Below are ui.R and server.R.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Art and R"),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
            "colspa", "Color space", choices = list("RGB" = "rgb", "HSV" = "hsv", "LAB" = "lab", "LCH" = "lch"), selected = 1
        ),

        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "", selectInput(
                "colchoice", "Sub-choice", choices = list("Red" = "r", "Green" = "g", "Blue" = "b"), selected = 1
            )
        ),

        actionButton("btn", "Graph!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
        highchartOutput("distPlot", height = "500px")
    )
)
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

art.data <<- read.csv(file = "data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$colspa, {
    if(input$colspa == "rgb") {
        myChoices <- c("Red" = "r", "Green" = "g", "Blue" = "b")
    }
    else if (input$colspa == "hsv") {
        myChoices <- c("Hue" = "h", "Saturation" = "s", "Value" = "v")
    }
    else if (input$colspa == "lab") {
        myChoices <- c("Luminance" = "l", "Red-Green" = "a", "Yellow-Blue" = "b")
    }
    else {
        myChoices <- c("Lightness" = "l", "Chroma" = "c", "Hue" = "h")
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "colchoice", choices = myChoices)
})

calculate <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    str1 <<- paste0(input$colspa, ".", input$colchoice, ".median")
    modlss <- loess(art.data[[str1]] ~ year, data = art.data)
    fit <- augment(modlss) %>% arrange(year)

    hc <- highchart() %>% 
        hc_add_series(art.data, "scatter", hcaes(x = year, y = art.data[[str1]])) %>% 
        hc_add_theme(hc_theme_elementary()) %>%
        hc_add_series(fit, type = "spline", hcaes(x = year, y = .fitted), name = "Fit",
                      id = "fit")

    hc
})

output$distPlot <- renderHighchart({
    calculate()
})
})
```

Below is part of art.data dataframe.

[image: art.data snap]

Comment: I suspect the slowness comes from `loess(art.data[[str1]] ~ year, data = art.data)` but since there is no data.csv for us to test, it can only be a guess.

Comment: Have a look at the `profvis` package to see the exact source of the problem https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/index.html

Comment: I think there is a bit of "reactivity mess" in your code. To use a `reactive` to calculate an heavy duty functions is correct.  To have the rendering part of the chart in same reactive is odd at best.  Let the reactive generate a vector (or a list) of parameters.  Move the rendering to the `renderHighchart` function (calling the reactive to get the list of parameters)  from within the function (same as your code, but passing only the parameters).  Check using the reactivity trace in `shiny` that all components are called only a minimal amount of time.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438920/shiny-selectinput-very-slow-on-larger-data-15-000-entries-in-browser