# Render data dictionary in UI- R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am building a Rshiny app and have a huge data dictionary that binds to one UI field containing 36k values. As I change tabs that data dictionary always reloads. Is there a way to load the dictionary in the UI on login and store in cache or session cookie and on logout clear the cache. Essentially load the data dictionary only on login and reload from the UI and the not server

Comment: What do you call a "dictionary" ? You should provide some code.

Comment: Dictionary here is list of Gene names around 36000 gene names as drop down values to select from

Comment: selectizeInput(inputId = 'hgnc_enter', 'HGNC Gene',
                         choice = c('Enter a HGNC Symbol', hgnc), multiple = FALSE,
                         selected = "TSPAN6", options = list(create = TRUE))

Comment: This is not clear. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You won't get some help from such a question.

Comment: Two approaches (server side or use data.table) already presneted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438920/shiny-selectinput-very-slow-on-larger-data-15-000-entries-in-browser