# How to know that an selectizeInput is ready to get updated by updateSelectizeInput?

Tags: r, shiny

My goal is to create a selectizeInput and update it directly after it exists via `updateSelectizeInput()`.

For various reasons, my selectizeInput is not created when the app starts. This only happens in the server with `renderUI()` when the user opens a `modalDialog()` via an `actionButton()`. Also my `selectizeInput()` should be created with `choices = NULL` and `selected = NULL`. As soon as the selectizeInput exists, the arguments "choices" and "selected" are to be filled via `updateSelectizeInput()`. This does not work because `updateSelectizeInput()` runs in the server before the input exists.

Current workaround: I call `updateSelectizeInput()` in an `observeEvent(input$selectize, once = TRUE)`, which runs as soon as the input exists (but only once).

Problem with workaround: Only works the first time. If the `modalDialog()` is closed and reopened, the inputs are recreated, but the observer is destroyed and cannot run again.

**Goal: `updateSelectizeInput()` should run as soon as the input is created and ready to be updated with `updateSelectizeInput()`. But how to know that my input is ready?**

I have created two working examples. In the first example, the problem occurs every time the modal is opened.

```
# example 1
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    actionButton("go", "go"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = "selectize",
            label = "selectize",
            choices = NULL,
            selected = NULL
          ),
          textOutput("text")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
    updateSelectizeInput(
      inputId = "selectize",
      choices = c("A", "B"),
      selected = "B"
    )
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    input$selectize
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the second example (with workaround), the filling works the first time the modal is opened, but it does not work the second time.

```
# example 2
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    actionButton("go", "go"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
      tagList(
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = "selectize",
          label = "selectize",
          choices = NULL,
          selected = NULL
        ),
        textOutput("text")
      )
    )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$selectize, once = TRUE,{
    updateSelectizeInput(
      inputId = "selectize",
      choices = c("A", "B"),
      selected = "B"
    )
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    input$selectize
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When you say "choices" and "selected" are to be filled via updateSelectizeInput()" are the new choices dynamic, meaning they will not always be the same when the modal opens?

Comment: In my real app I have several inputs. Some always have the same (static) choices, others are dynamic. However, I also want to fill the static choices via `updateSelectizeInput()`, because the initial filling in `selectizeInput()` can be slow (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438920/shiny-selectinput-very-slow-on-larger-data-15-000-entries-in-browser?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your first code one option would be to use a `reactiveVal` to store the state of the `selectizeInput`, i.e. whether it has been created and is ready to be filled or not. When `TRUE` it triggers the updating via an `observeEvent`. Inside this `oberseEvent` the `reactiveVal` is reset to `FALSE`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    actionButton("go", "go"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  is_ready <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    is_ready(TRUE)
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = "selectize",
            label = "selectize",
            choices = NULL,
            selected = NULL
          ),
          textOutput("text")
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(is_ready(), {
    is_ready(FALSE)
    
    updateSelectizeInput(
      inputId = "selectize",
      choices = c("A", "B"),
      selected = "B"
    )
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    input$selectize
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```